# Can I open geo files in 3dsmax?

Tags: 3d, geo, 3dsmax

Does 3dsmax read .geo files? If not, please tell me how to open such a file.

Answer (score 1):

Not without a converter \ import plugin.
3dsmax supports the following import formats:

```
 3D Studio (*.3DS, *.PRJ)
Adobe Illustrator (*.AI)
LandXML / DEM / DDF (*.XML, *DEM, *.DDF)
Autocad Drawing (*.DWG, *.DXF)
Legacy Autocad (*.DWG)
Autodesk FBX (*.FBX, *.DAE)
Motion Analysis HTR File (*.HTR)
IGES (*IGE,*.IGS,*.IGES)
Autodesk Inventor (*.IPT, *.IAM)
Lightscape (*.LS, *.LP, *.VW)
Wavefront Object (*.OBJ) and Material (*.MTL)
3D Studio Shape (*.SHP)
StereoLitho (*.STL)
Motion Analysis TRC File (*.TRC)
VRML (*.WRL, *WRZ)
VIZ Material XML (*.XML)
```